# CanvasRenderer not rendering in IE and lag in FF

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, html5-canvas, three.js, lag

so I'm rather new to Three.js but I have managed to create what I want using CanvasRenderer the only problem is that the code isn't working in IE and it's "lagging" in FireFox.

IE normally has some kind of issue no matter what it is trying to do, that's what makes it so special. And I understand that the lag in FireFox can come from my own end but a lot more "advanced" and heavy things run well in FireFox so I'm thinking it has something to do with my code.

Anyways, I was hoping that someone could take a look at my code and possibly explain why it's not working in IE and why it's slow in FireFox and hopefully point me in the right direction so I can take certain actions to try and fix this.

The code is here down below, and you can see a live example yourself by going here, http://ecaz.net/ThreeJS/redZone/

```
var camera, scene, renderer, plane;
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.screen.width / window.screen.height, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.z = 475;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    var planeTexture = new THREE.Texture();
    var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();

    loader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
        planeTexture.image = event.content;
        planeTexture.needsUpdate = true;
    });
    loader.load("redzone.png");
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(window.screen.width, window.screen.height, 200, 4, 4, 4);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: planeTexture, overdraw: true });

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(plane);
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.screen.width / window.screen.height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

    mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX) / 190;
    mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY) / 50;

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();

}

function render() {

    camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.1;
    camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.1;

    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your plane has 800 faces. Do this instead:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(window.screen.width, window.screen.height, 4, 4);
```

Also, your image is 4.6 Meg.

Comment: I had noticed that too and when I tested in IE it wouldn't load until I turned on the developer tools.

Comment: Right, that seems like a stupid thing to have now that I think of it. I just wasn't sure how set up a plane as I couldn't find a newer demo for it. Anyways, it's a bit smoother in FireFox now but it's still just rendering as black in IE9. And the image is quite large because it's only a draft and it's quite a big image (2560x1600), I suppose the file size can have an effect in the "smoothness" of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

This would be too sloppy in a comment.  IE doesn't have a true console without the dev tools being loaded and running.  Try placing this snippet in your code before Three.JS has loaded.  It basically creates some dummy methods if the console isn't present.

```
if (typeof (console) === 'undefined') {
  var console = {}
  console.log = console.error = console.info = console.debug = console.warn = console.trace = console.dir = console.dirxml = console.group = console.groupEnd = console.time = console.timeEnd = console.assert = console.profile = function () {};
}
```